# Joomla 3 - template only works with category, will not show single article

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

If I set the menu link to be an article, it shows a blank page - if I set the menu to be a category blog, it all works fine... but when I want to show regular articles, and a single article it won't work - even if I remove all coding from the template 'index.php' file (besides the html and body tags etc) and add one word, it doesn't work. Just shows a blank page.

on this site both the homepage and 'About Us' are using the template in question, while other pages use protostar for now while I test.
e.g. 
Home page is working because it's a category blog, but this page is not working because it's an article: http://dev.addrenaline.com/acces/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=101

...but with protostar, articles are working just fine: http://dev.addrenaline.com/acces/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=108

Just to confirm, the template works fine on homepage (a category blog) and blank on inner pages - About Us page is assigned - but 'standard' templates work fine, like protostar, so the actual articles/etc are fine, it must be a template problem...

Comment: Why are you removing code from the index.php?

Comment: I only removed code to test, as a way to see if the template could work with the bare bones only... like <p>test</p> but it was still blank. All code has been returned, FYI.

Comment: "it must be a template problem..." -which can be a template override problem for the articles. Check if there is a html folder inside your template - rename it to something like html-off and see if article pages work. Also, where are you going and what are you trying to fix without error_reporting enabled?

Answer (score 1):

> "it must be a template problem..."

-which can be a template override problem for the articles.

For a quick check if this is the reason, see if there is a html folder inside your template - if yes, then rename it to something like html-off and see if article pages work.

Also, where are you going and what are you trying to fix without error_reporting enabled?